# Insert "New User" and update/set meta data at once

Tags: user-registration

The wordpress function wp_insert_user doesn't seem to set (overwrite) the input I give. (documentation shows you can't)
Trying to use: wp_insert_user using the returned userID also doesn't work.

Of course I could just make my own query but maybe I'm forgetting an option to insert this data using a existing function.

```
$userdata = array(
    //user login
    'user_pass'  => esc_attr( $_POST['pass'] ),
    'user_login' => esc_attr( $_POST['user'] ),
    'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ),

    //user meta
    'rich_editing' => false,
    'comment_shortcuts' => false,
    'show_admin_bar_front' => false,        
    'wp_user_level' => 0, 
    'wp_capabilities' => 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}' 
);

     $new_user_user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are best off doing is hooking into `user_register` and from there updating the user options you want them set to. Below is an example of disabling the admin bar for new users:

```
add_action("user_register", "sc_set_user_admin_bar_false_by_default", 10, 1);
function sc_set_user_admin_bar_false_by_default($user_id) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'show_admin_bar_admin', 'false' );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The [codex page for `wp_insert_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) lists all the values that it accepts. `comment_shortcuts`, and `show_admin_bar_front` will all need to be set with [`update_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta).

To handle `wp_user_level` and `wp_capabilities` you will need to use [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User).

You can use `$new_user_user_id` (long var name lol) for both `WP_User` and `update_user_meta()`